# Гугл скрипт: Копирование последней строки таблицы при внесении изменений в файл через гугл скрипт

Tags: google-apps-script

Помогите, пожалуйста, с написанием гугл скрипта.

Есть файл (гугл таблица), куда автоматически на лист 1 подтягиваются данные после заполнения формы на сайте.
В этом же файле на втором листе (лист 2) прописаны формулы, обрабатывающие данные с листа 1.

Как сделать так, чтобы при заполнении новой строки на листе 1, на листе 2 автоматически заполнялась новая строка, копируя значение предыдущей? (просто протянуть формулы - не подходит)

Заранее спасибо за помощь!
Только начинаю изучать эту область...

Comment: а чем вам формулы не нравятся? наверняка там можно без скриптов реализовать, вы бы хоть какую то тестовую таблицу привели, чтобы было понимание, что вы пытаетесь получить

Comment: @ZxNuClear, формулами-то можно, но это гораздо сложнее,.

Comment: все же не понятно ваше "заполнялась новая строка, копируя значение предыдущей". Правильно я понимаю, что у вас на втором листе есть некое значение, которое должно дублироваться такое количество раз, сколько ячеек заполнено на листе 1? И все же повторю, добавьте в вопрос ссылку тестовую гугл таблицу, заполните ее минимальными данными и желаемым результатом, чтобы можно было увидеть то, что вы хотите получить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вот этот код:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Лист1");
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Лист2");
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet1.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  sheet2.appendRow(values);
```

Comment: Супер!!! Глеб, большое спасибо за помощь!))) в последней строчке только изменила sheet1 на sheet2 и прям красота-восторг!!!

Comment: в результате поставила тригер на изменение файла и прописала скрипт так, вдруг кому-то пригодится...

Comment: var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Для скрипта");
const lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
const lastColumn = sheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn();
sheet.insertRowAfter(lastrow);
const sourceRange = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
const targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1, 1, lastColumn);
sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange)